# Optimize time complexity - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

i need to optimize the time complexity of the given code kindly help.it is written in javascript.

```
for(let i=0;i<userList.length;i++){
   let clientValues = [];
   for(let j=0;j<userList[i].clients.length;j++){
      for(let k=0;k<clientList.length;k++){
         if(userList[i].clients[j] === clientList[k].client_id){
             clientValues.push(clientList[k].clientName);
         }
      }
    }
         userList[i].clients = clientValues;
}
```

Comment: To understand the time-complexity, it'd be useful to know the relative sizes of each `clientList`, `userList` and average length of `userList[i].clients` over  `i`.

Comment: they are dynamic ... i just wanna curb the nesting of 'for's. @BryceCicada

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `clientList` is reasonably large, one option is to iterate over it only once to create a map that can be used as a constant-time lookup on each iteration of `userList` and `userList[i].clients`:

```
let clientMap = new Map(clientList.map(c => [c.client_id, c.clientName]))
userList.forEach(u => {
    u.clients = u.clients
       .map(c => clientMap.get(c))
       .filter(c => c !== undefined)
})
```